# Fire event when user changes active process

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there an event, or a way to create an event, that fires when the program user changes the active window to that of a different process?

If there is no such event, what is the best way to make something that is something like it?

I'm currently having a timer that runs Process.GetCurrentProcess() every 3 seconds, but I'm searching for better and more efficient ways of doing it and I don't want to lower the interval because of the risk of making the program take too much resources or that it takes too much time to constantly check for the active process.

I know that there is a lot of Windows built in functions that is basically hidden that I don't have enough knowledge to know of, so if anyone have any idea of something like this, it would be great if you could help me out.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by getting the current process. Do you mean the current active window? Because there are more than one processes running constantly on your PC. ;)

Comment: Elaborate on the "why" of it.  You could react to lost focus, for instance, if that's all you care about.

Comment: It really depends on exactly what you are trying to achieve, what is it you are trying to do?

Comment: Are you building a multi-processes application? `Process.GetCurrentProcess()` will return the current process in which that method is called. I've not experienced with a multi-processes application, so not enough words to say because there are some significant terms to understand first...

Comment: Yeah I mean the active window, sorry :)
I want to be able to see whenever the user of the program changes the active window to another program, and then I'll get that program's process. =)
And it would be very useful if it's possible to check wether or not there is no current active window, when clicking the desktop for example.

Comment: You can accomplish this using windows hooks, see [.NET/Win32 - event to detect when a window belonging to another app gets focus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150895/net-win32-event-to-detect-when-a-window-belonging-to-another-app-gets-focus)

Comment: In that link, he already have the window handle though. I don't. I just want to be able to get the active window process, whenever it changes, without having to constantly check for it.

Comment: @stripe103 did you read the answer to the question? Using `SetWinEventHook` you don't pass any window handle, you pass it a pointer to the function you want to handle the notification and pass 0  for the process ID which would handle all active processes on the desktop. When your app starts up you would hook into this API passing the appropriate flags and your app would start receiving notifications when you switch windows.

Comment: Oh okay. I guess I misunderstood the answer then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [SetWinEventHook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd373640%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API does exactly what you are looking for here. All you need to do is call this when your app starts up with the correct options and you should start to receive notifications whenever the user changes focus from any processes currently running on the desktop.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern IntPtr SetWinEventHook(uint eventMin, uint eventMax, IntPtr hmodWinEventProc, WinEventProc lpfnWinEventProc, int idProcess, int idThread, uint dwflags);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
internal static extern int UnhookWinEvent(IntPtr hWinEventHook);
internal delegate void WinEventProc(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint iEvent, IntPtr hWnd, int      idObject, int idChild, int dwEventThread, int dwmsEventTime);

const uint WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT = 0;
const uint EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND = 3;
private IntPtr winHook;
private WinEventProc listener;

public void StartListeningForWindowChanges()
{
    listener = new WinEventProc(EventCallback);
    //setting the window hook
    winHook = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, IntPtr.Zero, listener, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT);
}

public void StopListeningForWindowChanges()
{
    UnhookWinEvent(winHook);
}

private static void EventCallback(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint iEvent, IntPtr hWnd, int idObject, int idChild, int dwEventThread, int dwmsEventTime)
{
    // handle active window changed!
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to get the EventCallback() to fire. I changed the SetWinEventHooks variables eventMin, eventMax and dwflags to be uint's so that the code compiled, would that be why?
I'm running StartListeningForWindowChanges() upon start of the application and StopListeningForWindowChanges() before closing it. Is there anything else that needs to be done?

Comment: @stripe103 Sorry that was my fault, I had a mixture of `int`/`uint` and there was also an old enum type in the signature which I changed... I have updated the answer to use `uint` consistently where the API requires it.

Comment: No worries, considering you're so quick at answering =)
I still can't seem to get EventCallBack() to fire though. Is there something else that needs to be done other than running StartListeningForWindowChanges()?

Comment: @stripe103 nope the above should work, just out of curiosity are you trying to run this in a console app? Your application needs to be running a message pump (which console windows don't). Try it in a WinForms application and let me know if it's still not working.

Comment: I've put the methods in a partial class file that is using my main form in my program, so it should be constantly going.

Comment: @stripe103 ah ok, can see what the issue is. I am using the `INCONTEXT` flag which means the callback would have to be in it's own DLL, you need to use `OUTOFCONTEXT` - see updated answer.

Comment: Awesome, now something happens when changing the active window at least. However, it's an error. When the EventCallback() finishes, it gives me this error:
"A callback was made on a garbage collected delegate of type '(Project name)!(Project Name).mainForm+WinEventProc::Invoke'. This may cause application crashes, corruption and data loss. When passing delegates to unmanaged code, they must be kept alive by the managed application until it is guaranteed that they will never be called.".

Comment: @stripe103 you just need to make the `listener` object a private field in that case, see update.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! =D
Just to make sure, will this one only react to active window changes or is there something I should watch out for?

Comment: No worries :) The `SetWinEventHook` can be used to trap various [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318066(v=vs.85).aspx), as part of the API call you pass a range in. In my example, we have limited that range to only trap `EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND` which should only notify you when the foreground window has changed i.e. when a new window has taken focus. Bare in mind this will happen **per window** and not per process, so you will receive multiple notifications when switching between windows in the same process.

Comment: If you want to only raise a single notification per window changed per process, then you will have to add some logic to keep track of the process ID which the window belongs to and whether or not it has changed from the last notification (the process ID which the window belongs to is passed into the callback).

Comment: Just to check if I'm using the right process ID, or if I'm just a tad stupid right now, I'm trying to get the activated process using "Process.GetProcessById(dwEventThread);", but it seems like the method just stops there and returns to the normal program, without doing the rest in the event.

I tried comparing hWnd to Process.Handle as well, but it did the same, just stopped processing the method. I still have some things to learn about Window handles, but for now, could you direct me to what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I would say one of the ways is to employ Windows hooks, namely CBT hooks. It sounds closer to "old good" Win32 API and generic C/C++ staff. Same time, as far as I can see there is C# version as well http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188966.aspx#S5

So idea is to check current process every time you get HCBT_ACTIVATE type of hook event (window to be activated), then check the process that owns that window. If it doesn't match with previously remembered process - it's time to fire your event. The only thing to remember that your own actions may trigger CBT hook as well (you have to avoid endless self-propelled loops!).

Comment: Hmm.. I don't quite get exactly what you mean, since this is quite some way out of my knowledge, but I'll do some research. Thanks for the answer! Looks right, so I'll tick it as the answer =)