# Fire window resize events C#

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke, win32-process

I am working on a project in which I have to first split and then re size the the windows on desktop. I am able to split the desktop screen by using pinvoke service `TileWindows`. But i am stuck in the other part, to resize the windows on desktop. Because first I have to catch the event that some window is re sized on the desktop. To catch this event I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222788/fire-event-when-user-changes-active-process) code answered in SO.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern IntPtr SetWinEventHook(uint eventMin, uint eventMax, IntPtr hmodWinEventProc, WinEventProc lpfnWinEventProc, int idProcess, int idThread, uint dwflags);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
internal static extern int UnhookWinEvent(IntPtr hWinEventHook);
internal delegate void WinEventProc(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint iEvent, IntPtr hWnd, int      idObject, int idChild, int dwEventThread, int dwmsEventTime);

const uint WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT = 0;
const uint EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND = 3;
private IntPtr winHook;
private WinEventProc listener;

public void StartListeningForWindowChanges()
{
    listener = new WinEventProc(EventCallback);
    //setting the window hook
    winHook = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, IntPtr.Zero, listener, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT);
}

public void StopListeningForWindowChanges()
{
    UnhookWinEvent(winHook);
}

private static void EventCallback(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint iEvent, IntPtr hWnd, int idObject, int idChild, int dwEventThread, int dwmsEventTime)
{
    MessageBox.Show("I am here");
}
```

the problem I am getting is the event is fired even when i have not re sized any window on screen. And as you can see I have put a `messageBox` in the `eventCallback` function and it pops up but interestingly it shows nothing on its `ok` button.

Comment: That is because you are not listening for resize events, EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND tells you when a window moves into the foreground.  Use EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZEEND or EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE instead.

Comment: thanks, I have changed it to MOVESIZEEND and it is now firing on resize but still is is firing continuously even when i have not resized anything. And the also message box is showing nothing on it.

Comment: frankly speaking I am using pinvoke for the first time so my qyestions may look stupid questions.

Comment: If an answer solved your question you should click the check mark to the left of the answer. If you solved it yourself you should post it as an answer; after a few days you can check your own answer. You should not change the title to “[solved]” as that does not mark the question solved in the site.

Answer (score 2):

As @HansPassant already said you should use the

- `EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZEEND` = `0x000B` constant that indicates that: The movement or resizing of a window has finished.

[Event Constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318066(v=vs.85).aspx)

you are also receiving events from ANY window. If you look at the signature of [`SetWinEventHook` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
HWINEVENTHOOK WINAPI SetWinEventHook(
  _In_  UINT eventMin,
  _In_  UINT eventMax,
  _In_  HMODULE hmodWinEventProc,
  _In_  WINEVENTPROC lpfnWinEventProc,
  _In_  DWORD idProcess,
  _In_  DWORD idThread,
  _In_  UINT dwflags
);
```

you'll find that:

- **`idProcess`** - Specifies the ID of the process from which the hook function receives events. Specify zero (0) to receive events from all processes on the current desktop.

however in your code you have spacified a `0` there:

```
winHook = SetWinEventHook(
    EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, 
    EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, 
    IntPtr.Zero, 
    listener, 
    0, // <--- idProcess
    0, 
    WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT);
```

You need to get your process' ID to listen only for events about your window. For that you can use the [`Process.Id` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.id(v=vs.110).aspx). I think this should work (it works for me):

```
const uint EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZEEND = 0x000B;

Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

winHook = SetWinEventHook(
    EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZEEND, 
    EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZEEND, 
    IntPtr.Zero, 
    listener, 
    currentProcess.Id, 
    0, 
    WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT);
```

Comment: Not sure what you are saying. The link you have mentioned says that specify 0 to listen from all processes on desktop. Thats what i need, to listen from all processes on desktop.

Comment: Oh, I thought you want to resize only you own windows, my bad ;-]