# How to detect the window has been maximized?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I have my application and third-party application. And I need to know that the window of third-party application has been maximized. Is there any way to know it? 
At first, I thought that I could use my own callback function for handling events of this window.

```
SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG)WindowProc);
```

But this function fails with error "Access denied". And this happens for a reason. It's not very wise to change something in the window that you don't own. 

So what should I do?

Comment: This is a similar problem to yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150895/net-win32-event-to-detect-when-a-window-belonging-to-another-app-gets-focus

Comment: @RedX Thanks. But that's funny: I cannot find any events connected with "maximizing" the window. And, apparently, it doesn't exist at all.

Answer (score 5):

Use [GetWindowPlacement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633518%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. Make sure you set the length member of WINDOWPLACEMENT to sizeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT) before calling GetWindowPlacement.

The showCmd field of the returned WINDOWPLACEMENT structure should be equal to SW_MAXIMIZE (3) if the window is maximized.

Comment: May be I don't understand something, but isn't it just for finding out the property of the window? Meanwhile I need to get an event each time the window is maximized.

Comment: No, you won't get an event each time when the window is maximized. Using this function you can get the current placement and state of the Window. Though you can create a thread and fire this function at regular intervals (using loop/timer) to check whether the third party window is maximized.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually get notified when a window is about to be minimized or maximized. You will need to use the SetWindowsHook procedure to install and listen to a WH_CBT_Hook.

Here's the general information about WIndowsHooks:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/winui/WinUI/WindowsUserInterface/Windowing/Hooks/AboutHooks.asp

Here's a thread that shows you how to do something smiliar (for a WH_Mouse_Hook) in VB:

http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=581752&SiteID=1

Hope this helps,

Comment: That, actually, means that I should place my callback function in a Dll. Unfortunatelly, this way doesn't suit me well. But thanks for the tip.